# Google analytics reports filtered to show mobile users only

Tags: google-analytics

There is a deadline this april (2015) where Google are going to start seeing if you site is mobile accessible and penalise any pages in mobile search that are not.

A site Im working on isnt mobile accessible (apart from having the viewport meta set, but you have so zoom and scroll etc). Im trying to work out if for me this penalty will be a big deal and quantify if i should spend time over the next couple of weeks to convert this website to be mobile accessible.

The data Im trying to find out for this study in Google Analytics are :

- % of mobile users that come to my site and via which sources (I can find how many mobile visitors im getting for the whole site and how many visitors from which sources im getting for the whole site, but cant seem to find how to get a report showing mobile visitors by source (Im looking for this as in this sites niche i would say 99% of leads / convertible traffic come from organic search engine traffic and one other referrer site) so id like to see how much mobile traffic comes from that)
- How long visitors on mobiles stay on my site currently and their bounce rates
- Their geographic locations (i know this isnt super accurate, but would be useful to know the mobile users country)

Does any one know how to do this in Google Analytics ? The problem im having so far finding it is being able to find all the info specificly for mobile visitors, i can find it at the moment for the whole site only

Comment: There is no penalty. It is just a small boost. Here is an answer on that: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77692/is-it-true-that-google-will-effectively-penalise-mobile-unfriendly-sites-from-ap/77694#77694 It is a minor effect only for mobile search. Again- not a penalty!! Is it worth focusing on mobile? Yes. But weigh that against other work. I have a mobile friendly site ready to go, but other new content work is more important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so easy, just make this report and You will find all what You need (All traffic - Channels first):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new view just for mobile traffic. It will allow you to analyze your mobile traffic in a number of ways. Here are the steps:

1) Go to **Admin** in Google Analytics. Make sure that the correct property is selected.

2) On the third Column click on the dropdown and "**Create New View**". Name your something like "Mobile Only" and save

3) With your new view selected click **Filters** and create a new filter

4) Select **Custom** -> **Include** -> **Mobile?** See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out creating a segment for your mobile users and compare it to all users or e.g. tablet or desktop users. For any report you're looking at, choose +Add segment above the chart and select Mobile Traffic to create the segment. Then you can compare your metrics, such as the ROI, between mobile users and all visitors on your site or any other segment you have created.