# Measure mobile website success in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am ready to start the mobile version of my small ecommerce site. Is there any way to measure the success of the mobile version vs. normal site in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a specific segments for your mobile users and compare it to all users or e.g. tablet or desktop users. For any report you're looking at, choose *+Add segment* above the chart and select *Mobile Traffic* to create the segment. Then you can compare your metrics, such as the ROI, between mobile users and all visitors on your site or any other segment you have created.

You can also create custom reports, more about that in this thread [Google analytics reports filtered to show mobile users only](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78902/google-analytics-reports-filtered-to-show-mobile-users-onlyv)